# Alternative to Get-Service for Remote Computer in Powershell V6.0

Tags: powershell-v6.0

I have a script that uses Get-Service to see if a particular service exists and is running on a group of computers.

```
Get-Service -Name "ServiceName" -Computername "PCName"
```

In Powershell V6.0 the Get-Service cmdlet doesn't have the -Computername parameter.  I can't seem to find another way to see the status of a service on a remote computer in Powershell V6. The computers I am checking don't have Powershell Remoting enabled on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details on how you run remote commands in PowerShell 6+ [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6).

In your specific example you can try using `Invoke-Command`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName PCName -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -Name "ServiceName"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but unfortunately, I cannot use `Invoke-Command` since WinRM may not be enabled on all of the computers. I can always continue to use powershell 5.1 for the time being if this is an impossible request.